# Find Maximum Pairs in Haskell based on the Sum of the tuples

Tags: haskell, syntax, pattern-matching

I'm currently completely new to Haskell programming and honestly, I'm completely lost. My current problem is trying to figure out how to get the maximum element in a list of tuples.

Example:

Given a list [(2, 4), (7, 5), (2, 1), (3, 4)] find the maximum pair based on the sum of the tuples.
In this case, the answer would be (7, 5) because 7 + 5 = 12 which is greater than all the other sums.

Currently, this is the code that I have:

```hs
maximumPair [] = error "List needs at least one element"
maximumPair ((x, y):[]) = [(x, y)]
maximumPair ((x, y):xys) = maxPair 
  where maxPair currentMax[] = currentMax
  | sum [x, y] > currentMax = maxPair xys
  | otherwise = (x, y) : maxPair
```

I tend to keep getting parse errors and just generally seem to be doing things wrong in terms of syntax. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `maximumPair =`[`maximumBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy)`.`[`comparing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing)`$ uncurry (+)`

Comment: Please state the exact error messages you get. Edit the question for that, a question should stand on its own without having to read through comments.

Comment: Forget pairs for the moment.  Can you write a function that finds the maximum element of a list of integers?  Hint: you should be able to do it in two lines:  `maximumInt [x] = ...` and `maximumInt (x:xs) = ...something recursive using max...`; the `maximumInt [] = error "empty list"` case is optional.  Do that, and post the answer here, and we can help you modify it to handle pairs.

Answer (score 4):

Don't panic. You're definitely on the right track. Let's go over it case by case.

**Empty list**

Indeed, if your list of pairs is empty, there is no maximum:

```
maximumPair [] = error "maximumPair: empty list"
```

**Non-empty list**

If the list has at least one element, we traverse it while keeping track of the pair with the highest sum encountered so far. We implement this traversal with a helper function `go` that takes two arguments: (1) the pair with highest sum encountered so far (the "candidate") and (2) the part of the list that is still to be traversed. As we begin the traversal, we pick as a first candidate the first element in the list: it's the first pair we encounter and so it definitely is the pair with the highest sum encountered so far:

```
maximumPair (pair : pairs) = go pair pairs
```

**Traversal**

The function `go` that performs the traversal is a run-of-the-mill recursive function over lists. In each step of the recursion we test whether a newly encountered pair has a higher sum than the candidate: if it has, the newly encountered pair becomes the candidate; otherwise, we keep the candidate unchanged. If we reach the end of the list, the candidate is established to be the maximum element and is returned as the function result. For comparing the sums of pairs we use a helper function `lt` ("less than").

```
go candidate [] = candidate
go candidate (pair : pairs) | candidate `lt` pair = go pair pairs
                            | otherwise           = go candidate pairs

lt (m, n) (p, q) = m + n < p + q
```

**Wrapping up**

The complete definition for `maximumPair` now reads:

```
maximumPair :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a, a)] -> (a, a)
maximumPair []             = error "maximumPair: empty list"
maximumPair (pair : pairs) = go pair pairs
 where
  go candidate [] = candidate
  go candidate (pair : pairs) | candidate `lt` pair = go pair pairs
                              | otherwise           = go candidate pairs

  lt (m, n) (p, q) = m + n < p + q
```

Testing it yields:

```
> maximumPair [(2, 4), (7, 5), (2, 1), (3, 4)]
(7,5)
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. Thank you for explaining everything!

Comment: @TerribleProgrammer Well, you could accept the answer. ;-) In any case, you're welcome. Writing recursive definitions like this takes a bit of practice, but it's quite powerful and fun once you get the hang of it. Happy coding!

Comment: I was able to get it to work! Sorry for the long time between responses. But yes, the code was my own attempt. Your response helped me understand some things that I wasn't quite getting so thank you! I did change some things, but in the end, it worked!